Не понимаю в чем проблема discord.py
Хочу сделать своего бота на python используя библеотку disnake вот код
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands


class Guild(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.slash_command(
        name="mute",
        description="Замутить игрока сервера",
        )
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, members: disnake.Member = None, reason=None):
        guild = ctx.guild
        mutedrole = disnake.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Mute")

        if mutedrole in members.roles:
            embed = disnake.Embed(
                color=disnake.Color.red(),
                description=f'Этот пользователь уже в муте'
                )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        await members.add_roles(mutedrole)
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            color=disnake.Color.green(),
            title='Мут',
            description=f'**{members.mention}** теперь в муте **Бесконечно** reason: **{reason}**}}'
            )

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Guild(bot))

проблема в том что при команде /mute после того как выдается роль mute бот должен отправить embed сообщение, вместо этого приложение не отвечает

Попробуйте вместо
await ctx.send(embed=embed)

использовать
await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)

